# Remove duplicates from custom search query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a search method that combines the results from doing a fuzzy search using the fuzzily gem and doing a search in the tags used in acts_on_taggable gem.

```
if params[:search]
  results = Post.find_by_fuzzy_title(params[:search])
  tagged_results = Post.tagged_with("#{params[:search]}")
  @posts = (Kaminari.paginate_array(results+tagged_results)).page(params[:page]).per(1)
else
```

The problem is that the returned query contains a concatenation of the two individual queries with duplicate results. What I would like to do is make sure a result is displayed only once even if it contains both a matching title and a matching tag to the search keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this out of the ruby standard library

```
(Array1 + Array2).uniq
```